# Recovering transaction log from corrupt SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log

We have a database that is backed up weekly in simple mode.  Yesterday, we had a crc error corrupt the mdf file and we were unable to save it.  I restored the backup from last week, but now we have a gap from the time of the backup to the time of the restore.  Since I have the ldf file from that database, is there any way to "replay" that transaction log to fill in the gap?

I have tried reattaching the ldf file to the recovered mdf file, but SQL Server will not allow me to do that. (It just creates a new ldf file with a different name when I reattach the database.)

Any ideas would help.  This is a lot of data to lose and although it is not critical data, I'd like to get it back (as well as learn as well as learn how to do it.)

Comment: voting to mover to ServerFault.com

Comment: Hi Don, you might want to consider posting future questions on the admistration of systems as opposed to the programing to StackOverflows sister site http://serverfault.com/ you will get more answers from people who specilise in this stuff. Also if any answer has solved you issue it is nice to mark the answer as accepted the rewards the answerer and show hte person arriving from google that the answer works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you follow the instructions from [MSDN -How to: Restore to a Point in Time (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190982.aspx) you should be good.  I will not reproduce them here as they are quite long. There is also [MSDN - How to: Restore a Transaction Log Backup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177446.aspx)